# Why are sprites in contact with each other although they do not collide ?

Tags: swift, collision, contacts, skaction

I am trying to make a simple SpriteKit game. There are two sprites on the screen. One of them is shooting laser gun. When the laser goes through the screen it should be missed. **The bullet and the sprite are not in contact with each other but contact detection func call.** I do not figure out what is going on ? I am shooting from upper sprite with SkAction func. All sprites and laser gun have different UInt32 categorybitmask values.

Thanks for help.

```
var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
var sprite02 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
var actionMove = SkAction.scaleYTo(12, duration: 0.5)


    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height * 3/4)
    sprite.yScale = 0.2
    sprite.xScale = 0.2

    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
    sprite.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    sprite.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    sprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ship02.rawValue
    sprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.laser.rawValue
    sprite.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0

    self.addChild(sprite)

    sprite02.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height * 1/4)
    sprite02.yScale = 0.2
    sprite02.xScale = 0.2

    sprite02.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
    sprite02.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    sprite02.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    sprite02.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ship01.rawValue
    sprite02.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.laser.rawValue
    sprite02.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0

    self.addChild(sprite02)
```

I am checking the contact detection like this.

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    println(contactMask) 
}

    // Laser gun properties
    func laserNode(positionNode: CGPoint, rotationNode: CGFloat, name: String) -> SKSpriteNode {

    var laser = SKSpriteNode()


    laser.color = UIColor.greenColor()
    laser.position = positionNode
    laser.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    laser.size = CGSize(width: 3, height: 50)
    laser.zPosition = -1
    laser.zRotation = rotationNode
    laser.name = name

    laser.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: laser.size.width * 2, height: laser.size.height*2))
    laser.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    laser.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    laser.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.laser.rawValue
    laser.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.ship01.rawValue | BodyType.ship02.rawValue | BodyType.ship03.rawValue | BodyType.ship04.rawValue
    laser.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0


    laser.runAction(actionMove)
    laserArray.append(laser)


    self.addChild(laser)

    return laser
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had the exact same issue. I don't exactly know what the exact problem is but I fixed it by changing the hitbox of the sprites to circles instead of rectangles.
Try changing you declaration of the sprites Physic Bodies to this instead.

```
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sprite.size)

sprite02.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sprite.size)

laser.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGSize(width: laser.size.width * 2, height: laser.size.height*2))
```

I believe the issue lies in how the rectangular hitbox is placed around the sprite but if you change it to a circle it should work.

Comment: I try this but not working. Some problem exist.Thanks for comment.

Comment: Turn on `view.showsPhysics = true` in your `didMoveToView()` function to see where your physics boundaries exist

Comment: My guess is the way you made your boundaries is wrong, not the way you calculate the detection

Comment: One important thing to note is that swift doesn't recognize transparent parts of images so your hitbox especially for the bullet is probably too big.

Comment: Brennan Adler thanks for your answer. I understand where the problem is. Seeing "view.showPhysics = true " make my day. :)

Comment: :D no problem man haha, do you mind letting me know what the problem was just because I'm curious?

Comment: :)) i am using scaleYTo with anchor point 0.0. Sprite body is scalling up only, but physics body scales both up and down. So invisible contact occur :)) I learn from something you cannot scale physics body like sprite body. :)